# Making a matrix when samples that have missing data

Tags: matrix, differential-methylation

I am trying to make a dataset for methylation analysis.
I called methylation using Methyldackel and there are various positions without methylation calls. This creates a problem because when I try to use for example, DMCHMM or MethylSig, to estimate differentially methylated regions, the initial step prompts an error:

```r
Building BSData object.
Warning message:
In .merge_two_Seqinfo_objects(x, y) :
  Each of the 2 combined objects has sequence levels not in the other:
  - in 'x': NW_022883351.1, NW_022883409.1
  - in 'y': NW_022883010.1
  Make sure to always combine/compare objects based on the same reference
  genome (use suppressWarnings() to suppress this warning).
```

I used the same reference for all my samples, but when it tries to combine the files, it complains because some samples don't have data (missing) in some positions.

Is there a way to use R or Linux to fix this, and check those lines positions with missing data and add those (lines) positions in the files?

The files look like this:

```
chrBase chr     base    strand  coverage        freqC   freqT
NW_022882922.1.4856     NW_022882922.1  4856    F       2         0.00  100.00
NW_022882922.1.4866     NW_022882922.1  4866    F       2         0.00  100.00
NW_022882922.1.4889     NW_022882922.1  4889    F       4         0.00  100.00
NW_022882922.1.4892     NW_022882922.1  4892    F       4         0.00  100.00
```

so that all the files have "information" in all the positions?

Thank you

Juan Pablo